# How to handle BN and DO behavioural changes in subclassed models?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

So, batch normalization and dropout are layers that change behaviour depending on whether you're in training or inferencing phase. Usually, Keras takes care of that on behalf of me. But, if I'm doing custom training, how can I handle that?

What I've done: added if statement to bypass dropout layer while in inference mode

```
class mymodel(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(mymodel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=(2,))
        self.l2 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.9)
    def call(self, x, training=None):
        x = self.l1(x)
        if training:
            x = self.l2(x)
        return x
```

I'm not sure if that's all? And what about Batch normalization?

EDIT: my 'custom training loop' for the toy example above is:

```
def train_one_ste(model, batch)
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        output = model(batch)
    grad = tape.gradient(output, model.trainable_weights)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, model.trainable_weight)
```

Comment: The ```Dropout``` layer has a check for whether or not is running in training mode or not. So you do not need this check.

Comment: @PedroMarques How does it know? Remember that I won't be training with .fit method, I have a custom training loop.

Comment: What do you call a custom training loop? Please include exact code.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro like regular loop over batches, I pass batches to the model, get output, compute loss, compute graidient, backprop, update parameters, end of loop.

Comment: No, there is a reason why we ask for code, all of these details matter. What you think does not matter might actually matter.

Comment: Dropout implements a adds a conditional test in the graph whether it is in training mode or not here: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L126

Comment: @PedroMarques Thanks for the link. Yes, that's what I said in the question. Keras takes care of it for you IF you use functional API, but not when you write from scratch, you have to take care of it yourself.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I made edits to the question and included what you asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can control the learning phase manually, using `K.set_learning_phase(1)` during training, and `K.set_learning_phase(0)` during testing/inference. Here `K` is the module `keras.backend`.

Also note that to run one training step with a given batch, you can use `model.train_on_batch(x, y)`, in which case Keras will manage the learning phase for you.

Comment: That's easier than I thought. Thanks for the extra tip.